# Can't loop or map over FileReader blob

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I'm using the FileReader API to grab a file (preferably a JSON file) and then loop over the information exposed that way and display it to the page. I can grab the information and console log it but every time I try to .forEach or .map over it, it yells at me that I'm doing it wrong. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I've included a link.

https://jsfiddle.net/alexmarple/c7mco54p/4/

```
var fileInfo = document.getElementById('file-info');
var localArr;
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function(){
  var file = this.files[0];    
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var arr = event.target.result;
    localArr = arr;
    //console.log(arr);
    arr.forEach(function(item){
     console.log(item);
    });
  // scrub information
  // display in #file-info
 }
}, false);
```

Comment: What's the exact error message that you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target.result` is a String, not an Array. You need to `JSON.parse` it first:

```
reader.onload = function(event){
  var arr = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
  // ...
}
```

The way that you use `forEach` assumes the uploaded file contains an Array. If it's an Object, you could use `Object.keys` to iterate its properties:

```
reader.onload = function(event){
  var obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes you're looking at something and just not seeing the simplest of things. That fixed everything.